# How to remove lines where the first "word" is non-unique

Tags: regular-expression, ex-mode

I have a large data file of comma separated variables. I need to remove all lines where the first entry (a number up to four digits) is non-unique. A typical example of what I am working with is below

```
1062,"Mark","Michaelson","1"
1062,"Mark","Michaelson","2"
1062,"Mark","Michaelson","4120"
1075,"Dan","Danson",15"
1075,"Dan","Danson",185"
```

so in the brief example above, I wish to retain the first and forth lines and discard the rest.

I have been trying to use Vim Regex to achieve this

```
:0/^\w*/+,$g//d
```

but of course that deletes all lines apart from the first

Comment: If you don't mind having the result sorted and have access to a shell I would use the bash command `sort` like this: `sort -u -t, -k1,1 myfile` I know it is not in vim but it is a pretty straighforward way to do that. See [man sort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) `-u` is uniq result, `-t,` sets `,` as the delimitor and `-k1,1` gives the fields to use for the sort.

Comment: Is the input guaranteed to be sorted, like in your example?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem the input is not guaranteed to be sorted, though it is easy to do so if necessary.. I require any one of the unique lines, so for example retaining the second and fifth lines would be equally useful

Comment: @statox thanks, I will need to have a play.. I am using powershell to do as you suggest and am getting the errors `Missing argument in parameter list`. I will figure it out, I'm sure

Comment: @statox Thanks, I tried that on my Linux machine and worked a treat

Answer (score 1):

The `g/` only solution would probably be

```
:g/^\(\d\{4}\).\+\n\_.*\%(^\1\D\)/d
```

This leaves the last occurrence.  We look for lines which have another line starting with the same digits an arbitrary number of characters ahead.  The key is the `\_.*` in the middle which subsumes as much as possible.

The equivalent very magic version is

```
:g/\v^(\d{4}).+\n\_.*%(^\1\D)/d
```

Another solution is to use `:s` and the sub-replace-expression `\=`,

```
let seen = {} | %s/^\(\d\{4}\).\+\n/\= has_key(seen, submatch(1)) ? '' : execute('let seen[submatch(1)] = 1').submatch(0) /
```

This leaves the first occurrence.  It would be better to write a function if this is to be a commonly used operation.

Comment: thank you for your answer, unfortunately my file has so much data, vim just hangs when I attempt this, but I think that is a limitation of trying to do this within vim

Comment: Does the second approach with `%s` work?  It should be much more efficient, about O(n).   I guess I should have mentioned that the first approach is very inefficient, O(n^2) at least, potentially exponential depending on vim's internals

Comment: is that entered in ex mode? If so, vim complains it is not an editor command

Comment: Yes, ex mode or on the command line (`:`).  Works for me, maybe you have an old version of vim?  `execute(` was added a bit over a year ago.